# It says no such thing as canvas in python tinkter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I made a script:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Ball:
    def _init_(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25,fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,245, 245, 100)

    def draw(self):
        pass
ball = Ball(canvas,"red")


while 1:
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

It says there is no such thing as canvas and I am getting really confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `canvas()` is a function, not an argument or a variable. You have to add `()` if you want to properly call it.

```
self.canvas = canvas()
```

Comment: @UdayanS I am glad that it worked out :) can you please accept my answer and upvote it please? :))

Comment: Ok sure but it won't show cause I only have one reputation, I started a day before yesterday. So can you upvote my question also?

Comment: @UdayanS but when you accept my question it will be shown. second button below the downvote :)

Comment: Ok, I did it! The clap thing

Comment: Can you upvote my question? I only have 1 reputation point :(

Comment: This won't work. There is no function or class named `canvas`. The tkinter class is named `Canvas`. Plus, this is just the wrong answer. The code is clearly passing a canvas object into the `Ball` class; the class shouldn't be creating a new canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling the truth: you haven't defined `canvas` anywhere. You need to both create a root window and an instance of the `Canvas` class.

```
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(foll="both", expand=True)
ball = Ball(canvas,"red")
```